# Sparse Cross Entropy in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits in tensorflow, its possible to only calculate loss for specific rows by setting the class label to -1 (it is otherwise expected to be in the range 0->numclasses-1).

Unfortunately this breaks the gradient computations (as is mentioned in the comments in the source nn_ops.py).

What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
raw_classification_output1 = [0,1,0]
raw_classification_output2 = [0,0,1]

classification_output =tf.concat(0,[raw_classification_output1,raw_classification_output2])
classification_labels = [1,-1]

classification_loss =    tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(classification_output,classification_labels)

total_loss = tf.reduce_sum(classification_loss) + tf.reduce_sum(other_loss)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss)
changed_grads_and_vars = #do something to 0 the incorrect gradients
optimizer.apply_gradients(changed_grads_and_vars)
```

What's the most straightforward way to zero those gradients?

Comment: You could use [clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#clip_by_value) to clip your grandients.

Comment: Sorry, I am just not sure what you mean by "incorrect" gradients. The loss of rows with "-1" will be zero, which means your parameters do not take effect in the final loss, then why aren't them zeros?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to just multiply the classification loss by a similar tensor of 1's where the loss is desired, and zeros where it isn't. This is made easier by the fact that the loss is already zero where you don't want it to be updated. This is basically just a workaround for the fact that it still does some weird gradient behavior if you have loss zero for this sparse softmax. 
adding this line after tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits:

```
  classification_loss_zeroed = tf.mul(classification_loss,tf.to_float(tf.not_equal(classification_loss,0)))
```

It should zero out the gradients also.